# How can i get result's body and status with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I've been developing a simple RESTful API with NodeJS and Express. When the backend was done and operative, my next step was to make HTML forms to fill the database and consume the API. I decided that using jQuery to submit the data would be a nice idea to get some practice .
So basically I want to get from a `$.post` the body and status that my app's backend generates whenever it recieves a `POST` request. Here's the form's script:

```
$('#addcube').submit(function(event){

      //Stop the default behaviour of the submit button
      event.preventDefault(); 

      //Get the input values 
      var $form = $(this),
          postData = {
            nombre: $form.find('input[name="nombre"]').val(),
            brand: $form.find('input[name="brand"]').val(),
            capas: $form.find('input[name="capas"]').val(),
            kind: $form.find('input[name="kind"]').val()
          },

          url = $form.attr('action');

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType: "application/json",
        done: function(cube, textStatus, jqxhr){
          console.log(JSON.parse(cube));
        },
        fail: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown.msg);
        }
      });

    });
```

And here's the backend route for that post:

```
app.post('/api/cube', cubeController.addCubo);
```

Which is controlled by this script:

```
module.exports.addCubo = function(req, res){
    var Cube = require('../models/cube');
    console.log('POST');
    try{
        console.log(req.body);

        var cubo = new Cube({
            nombre  : req.body.nombre,
            brand   : req.body.brand,
            capas       : req.body.capas,
            kind        : req.body.kind
        });

        cubo.save(function(err){
            if(!err){
                console.log('Nuevo cubo guardado.');
                res.send(JSON.stringify(cubo));
                res.status(200);
            }else{
                console.log('Error al guardar: '+err);
                res.send('{"status":"400","msg":"bad_request"}');
                res.status(400);
            }
        });
    }catch(err){
        res.send('{"status":"500","msg":"internal_server_error"}');
    }
};
```

Comment: `response` is string, not `javascript` object; also `result` does not appear to have a `body` property?

Comment: @guest271314 Then what should I use to accomplish this task?

Comment: Parse result using `var obj = JSON.parse (result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `body` property exists at `response`, use . Set `$.post()` type to `json`, or use `JSON.parse()` at `.done()`. Also, if sending `error`, use `.fail()` to log messages

```
  var send = $.post(url, {
    nombre : name,
    brand  : marca,
    capas  : layers,
    kind   : tipo
  }, "json"); // set expected response type to `"json"`
  // Try to get the result
  send.done(function(cube, textStatus) {
    console.log(cube, textStatus)
  });
  // handle errors
  send.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown, errorThrown.msg)
  });
```

Comment: Okay, now the response that I get is `[Object object]`. Technically it works, but I don't understand why it isn't the json object that the backend sends back. Could you explain it to me, please? (This is my first project using NodeJS and my first ever web app).

Comment: @FunnyStunny _"Okay, now the response that I get is [Object object]."_ At `.done()` or `.fail()`?

Comment: At `.done()`, since there is no error thrown by `.fail()`. I've set the expected response type to "json", as you show in line 6.

Comment: Try removing `"json"` and using `console.log(JSON.parse(cube))`

Comment: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1_, which refers to the `console.log(JSON.parse(cube))`

Comment: What do you mean by error? Try using `JSON.stringify(res.send(cubo))` at server

Comment: Still throwing _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1_. Would it make any difference if I tried using the `$.ajax` structure instead of `$.post`?

Comment: Sure, try using `$.ajax()`.  Previous example given here was incorrect; it should probably be `res.send(JSON.stringify(cubo))`

Comment: Okay, i've tried using `$.ajax`, making it to `console.log(JSON.parse(cube))` at `done` function and logging the error thrown at `fail`. And now it doesn't even throw an error. It just logs nothing. And also, the server does `res.send(JSON.stringify(cubo))`

Comment: No value is logged at `.done()` or `.fail()`? Can you update Question with `js` that you tried?

Comment: Updated the script at the question

Comment: Tried without `JSON.parse()` at `.done()`? Can you set `Content-Type` header at response?

Comment: I've tried without `JSON.parse()` at `.done()` and added `setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')` header at response in the server. Still nothing logging.

Comment: Try version which was returning `[Object object]` again, with `res.send(JSON.stringify(cubo))` at server